# Work around large RewriteMap config sections

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config

Is anyone aware of a way you can split out a large (550KB) rewrite file into smaller sections?

The problem we have is that the old site had thousands of urls which need to be mapped but we can't map them due to the 250KB limit.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of:

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap configSource="config\RewriteMaps.LargePart1.config" />
        <rewriteMap configSource="config\RewriteMaps.LargePart2.config" />
        <rewriteMap configSource="config\RewriteMaps.LargePart3.config" />
        <rewriteMap configSource="config\RewriteMaps.LargePartX.config" />
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

The problem with this however is that the rewriteMap nodes are not sections so can't use configSource. Has anyone come up with an elegant solution to this before?

Answer (score 0):

We were stuck on this for a long while, we ended up writing our own 301 redirector. In sitecore it was in a pipeline patched after ItemResolver which consumes the large file (not included in any Web.configs). We could not use the "registry hack" option as it an Azure Service App and there is no (easy and cheap) access to the registry.

Answer (score -2):

I have been facing this problem as well and looked around for solutions. There is nothing in IIS modules to do this (spanning rewrite maps across multiple files)

I have solved it - the good old DOS way :)

I had a large rewrite map file (50000+ records) with logically (!) named Map sections.
What I have done is storing each map in its own Text file.
Map1.config
Map2.config
Map3.config

I have a 'header.config' which contains two lines

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
```

and footer.config has

```
</rewriteMaps>
```

Each Map config begins with the appropriately named
`<rewriteMap name="Map name" defaultValue="">`, has all the rewrites I want to plug in and then ends with the `</rewriteMap>` tag.

FINALLY - to generate my complete file, I use the COPY command in DOS !
I have setup a Batch file to generate this
GenerateRewriteConfig.bat which basically does this

```
COPY header.config + Map1.config + Map2.config + Map3.config + footer.config MySiteRewriteMaps.config
```

For ongoing updates, I modify the relevant MAP config file and run the GenerateRewriteConfig.bat !

I am now working on an automated script to pull out the various maps into individual files (in case someone has TOO MANY maps and needs to use this tool). I will send an update in a few weeks.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Can't understand, how this solution will help, if the result MySiteRewriteMaps.config still exceeds the maximum file size?

Comment: This doesn't solve the underlying issue of the file being too large when processed by IIS

Comment: We have been facing the same thing. We arrived at the same idea too :)

Our solution was done within ASP though. #GreatMinds